# SWIFTUI - How to navigate to the last view after reopening the app?

Tags: view, swiftui, navigation

I am developing a text base rpg game. There will be a lot of number of views; after every decision the user will navigate to a new view. But if the user closes the app and reopens it, they would lose all the progress and start from the main view.

Is there a way to create a "Continue" button to take the user to the last view they were on? Or Is there a way to open the last view directly when they reopen the app?

For example, the user will start from this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {

NavigationLink(destination: View1()) {

    Text(Start)

}
}
}
```

After playing for a while the user in on View28

```
struct View28: View {
var body: some View {

NavigationLink(destination: View29()) {

    Text(Do This)

}

NavigationLink(destination: View30()) {

    Text(Do That)

}
}
}
```

The user closes the game, reopens it, and he/she is on the ContentView again.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {

NavigationLink(destination: View1()) {

    Text(To View1)

}
NavigationLink(destination: LastViewedView()) {

    Text(Continue)

}
}
}
```

Is there a way to add a "Continue" button like above to take the user to the View28?

Or is there a way to program the app to reopen View28 directly?

Thanks.

Comment: You could add a key in UserDefaults that persists between sessions and when you open the app, check the UserDefault value.

Comment: I used UserDefaults for storing variables values but I don't know how to store which view the user was on.

Comment: I would store a String or Int value in UserDefaults and then use that value to figure out which view to present.

Comment: [Restoring Your App’s State with SwiftUI - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/restoring_your_app_s_state_with_swiftui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @nicksarno's suggestion I think I found a primitive way to solve the problem.

I created a global variable

```
  var ViewCounter = 0
```

And after every view, I added this code:

```
        // ViewCounter will take the value of which view it is on, and UserDefaults will save the value.
      .onAppear() {  
ViewCounter = 28
        UserDefaults.standard.set(ViewCounter, forKey: "Save1")
    }
```

And in the ContentView, first I retrieve the value for ViewCounter:

```
onAppear() {

guard let retrievedmsg1 = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Save1") else {return}
                ViewCounter = retrievedmsg1 as! Int
}
```

Then I created a state variable and created a function to match it with ViewCounter:

```
@State var SelfViewCounter = 0

func ViewCountCheck() {
        
        SelfViewCounter = ViewCounter
    }
```

Under onAppear, I called the function:

```
self.ViewCountCheck()
```

And finally, I created a start button and a navigation button conditions:

```
// This is to start the game
NavigationLink(destination: View1()) {
        Text("Start")
                 }

if SelfViewCounter == 1 {
        NavigationLink(destination: View1()) {
        Text("Continue")
        }
        } else if SelfViewCounter == 2 {
        NavigationLink(destination: View2()) {
        Text("Continue")
        }
        ...
```

I know it needs a lot of hardcoding and would take a lot of time to implement. But it works. I am pretty sure there needs to be a better way than this, so please add on. Thanks.